# 405 (Method Not Allowed) error on ajax in Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8, http-status-code-405

I am trying to call an ajax function in my Laravel 8 Project. But on every call I am getting error `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getReasonForVisit 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. I have tried many options like `changing post method to get, change url` etc. but no use. It would be helpful if someone can help me.

Here is my code.

**JS File**

```
function getReasonForVisit(catId) {
       
  $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
  });
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url : '/getReasonForVisit',
      data : {'catId' : catId },
      dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
  });
}

$('#treatment-category').on('change', function (){
   var catId = $(this).val();
   getReasonForVisit(catId);
});
```

**View**

```
<select class="form-control form-select" name="category" id="treatment-category">
                                        
   <?php $categories = App::make("App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentsController")->getTreatmentCategories(); ?>
   @foreach($categories as $cat)  
      <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->category_name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/getReasonForVisit', [App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentsController::class, 'getReasonForVisit'])->name('getReasonForVisit');
```

**Controller**

```
class AppointmentsController extends Controller
{
    public function getTreatmentCategories() {
       $categories = DB::table('treatment_category')->get();
       return $categories;
    }

    public function getReasonForVisit() {
       echo 111;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I did cleared my route cache. now it's showing error `CSRF token mismatch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. Actually I am missing csrf meta tag in my blade. So Now I added this code in view blade file in the `<head>` tag.

```
<head>
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change option `type` to `method`

```
 $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url : '/getReasonForVisit',
      data : {'catId' : catId },
      dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
  });
```

Comment: I have cleared my route cache, now the error is changed `CSRF token mismatch`. I changed type to method, still the same error

Comment: Do you have in <head> tag this meta?    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: you are right. I am missing this tag in view. Now the issue resolved